# Can't inject WSClient with Play 2.4

Tags: scala, playframework, guice, playframework-2.4

I am converting an existing app from Play 2.3 to Play 2.4.  I am attempting to get rid of dependencies on Global state as recommended.  In part of this, I am attempting to replace a dependency on `WS.client` and `play.api.Play.current` with the injectable `WSClient` API now provided. I am using Guice runtime injection.  Trying the below code/configuration I get a `NullPointerException` for `wSClient:WSClient`.

WebServiceProvider

```
trait WebServiceProvider {
  def getWS: WSClient
}

@Singleton
class DefaultWebServiceProvider @Inject ()(wSClient: WSClient) extends WebServiceProvider {
    override def getWS = wSClient
}
```

application.conf

`play.modules.enabled += "MyGuiceModule"`

MyGuiceModule.scala

```
class MyGuiceModule() extends AbstractModule {
  def configure: Unit = {
.....
    bind(classOf[WebServiceProvider]).to(classOf[DefaultWebServiceProvider])
...
}
```

If I try to inject WSClient into a `Controller`, it doesn't throw the NPE but I don't need to inject there.  And with that in mind, this may be relevant as well.

build.sbt

```
...
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

**--Edit--**

MyController.scala (it works here but I do not want to inject here)

```
class MyController @Inject() (aService: AService, ws: WSClient) extends Controller
```

WebServiceUser.scala

```
trait WebServiceUser {

}

class DefaultWebServiceUser @Inject() (webServiceProvider: WebServiceProvider) extends WebServiceUser {

  val ws = webServiceProvider.getWS
  ...
```

Comment: Did you add the `@` before `mypackage.Class` in the routes file?

Comment: Did you update the dependency `play-ws` in `build.sbt`? If yes, a stack trace of your NPE might be helpful.

Comment: Post the controller code too.

Comment: Have you tried `bind[WebServiceProvider].to([DefaultWebServiceProvider]`?

Comment: I had been using javaWs in Play 2.3.  At one point, I did try updating the dependency to play-ws.  I can try that again. I did not try the Guice binding in the way Steve Chaloner indicated.  I already had @ before the name of my controllers in the routes file before attempting the transition.

Comment: Post the code where `WebServiceProvider` is being used. Maybe the NPE is related to `WebServiceProvider` and not `WSClient`.

Comment: I edited the post above with the code that uses WebServiceProvider.

Comment: I see @gogogadgetgeek is helping you and he is right. I have repeated your process and everything is ok. Probably the issue is in how WebServiceProvider is injected in aService. Because if I inject WebServicePrivder directly in the controller I get a properly configured instance of DefaultWebServiceProvider